# MATLAB gui freeze after running my program

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, neural-network, svm, matlab-guide

I create a GUI that use `Parallel computing` for accelerating `Neural network` and `SVM` models. When I enable `Parallel computing` in my GUI all thing (MATLAB,My GUI and my code's window) will freeze and I can't maximize these windows either, but my program is working,using workers and sometimes I can see updates in graphs and values of GUI. When I disable `Parallel computing` in my program everything is normal. In first situation sometimes my GUI turns to black color (Background of GUI,buttons,text-boxes and edit-boxes are good) but values are updating in iterations of created GUI.

What is this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a gui created with GUIDE?

Comment: Yes. I created it with GUIDE.

Comment: Ok, I just then I guess that the standard routines are quite stable. The I wonder, is the parallel computing something that runs all the time, or are you only running occasionally?

Comment: I can select in my GUI that I want use `parallel computing` or not. Default settings of this feature is on so in 90% I'm using `parallel computing` (`Parfor` loop).

Comment: Ok, but I rather meant that when you run the gui, does the parallel computing run from start and end when the gui is closed, or is the process inactive for some time when you run the gui?

Comment: My GUI use an optimization algorithm to optimize my neural network or SVM model. I repeat my neural network(training) or SVM sometimes with changing `parfor` loop and return the values to other functions (optimization codes). I'm not sure but in new version of MATLAB (R2014a) MATLAB close parallel computing (`parfor`) after ending. So all times I'm calling 'parfor' loop for cost calculation. + I didn't use any `parpool`before `parfor` in R2014a

Comment: Ok, but the gui just go black without you doing anything? And just to be sure, you are not trying to update the gui inside the `parfor`-loop right?

Comment: Yes. When I leave it alone and returns after a while all things is normal. If I move the gui,Minimize and Maximize it, it will freeze or sometimes background color turns to black. (Sometimes I can't maximize it after minimizing !)

Comment: OK I see. I have heard people having trouble with this, but I am not completely sure what causes it. **I also guess this is not a problem when you not run parallel computing?** However, I have a guess. The guess is that the plot data in matlab is stored as a pointer to some other location. When you moves the gui, matlab tries to reach this memory location. However, to prevent undefined bahaviour, the data cannot be accessed before the `parfor`-loop ends. This can make the gui to go black until it can update. Which may not be until after a while. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think that's true. When I use `getappdata` in parfor loop MATLAB can't run it because `getappdata` returns stored data from RAM. What do you think about GUI problem? Can we find any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. It is hard to give a definite answer to a solution here. The problem is quite advanced and most of the code we cannot do anthing about. What happens in `parfor` is probably that matlab puts some kind of lock (`mutex` or something else) on the elements it accesses at the moment. Also, since `parfor` works in parallel it is unlikely that any of the data in the loop is ever untouched. The only solution I can see is that you run shorter processes. That will allow your gui to update between the prcesses.

It would probably work to put a `drawnow` where you want the gui to update.

Other options could also be to place the gui in a location where you does not need to move it or dock it to the main window in matlab. But these are shortcuts which will only hide the problem.

Comment: Patrik, Thank you for your answer. I found a solution for this with your help. I put `pause(0.0001)` and `drawnow` in the end of `parfor` loop or after it. Now the time of turning black is 1 second. after 1 second the gui appearance is normal. With this solution now we can find a general solution for it. + I don't know now how remove it totally (1second to return to normal). Please add this answer, now We can talk about witch functions like `drawnow` or other functions we can use or where we should put these functions.

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick I guess. Normally, I would recommend to put the pause after the loop.

Comment: I think that the best solution is to have a draw now outside the `parfor` loop. I guess it is likely that you will halt each thread on the wrong time if you have it inside the loop. I have not seen your code, but on the description it seems as a program that will go on for a while and updates dynamically. This is probably driven by a while loop or so. Normally updating the screen is the last thing you do so I would recommend to have a `pause` or `drawnow` at the end of the main loop.

Comment: Thank you again for your helps. What is your recommendation for time duration of `pause` function?

Comment: @user2991243 that depends on the code. Just try to get it outside the `parfor loop`. This is the only recommendation.